# Using variable inside quotation marks?

Tags: c, linux

So I just have a simple question. How can I use a variable inside quotation marks?
For example

```
number =1
system (sudo asterisk -rx "pjsip show aor [number]")
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't edit your answered question to ask a different question. Just ask another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not that simple a question: you need to construct the string in memory at runtime, for example, by using [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

```
char command[100];
int number = 1;
sprintf(command, "sudo asterisk -rx \"pjsip show aor [%d]\"", number);
system(command);
```

The above code writes the command, including the value of `number` converted to decimal, into a `char[]` buffer called `command`, and passes this command to `system` for execution.